# LGBMRegressor MSE stays exactly the same despite hyperparameters differences (Python)

Tags: python, hyperparameters, lightgbm

I am working on a lightGBMRegressor today and I try to do some parameter tuning on the "n_estimators" by making it goes up while keeping other hyperparameters fixed.

```
import lightgbm as lgb
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import time

hyper_params = {
    'task': 'train',
    'boosting_type': 'gbdt',
    'objective': 'regression',
    'verbose' :-1,
    
    "n_estimators": 100,
    "learning_rate": 0.1,
    "max_depth": 5,
    "subsample":0.8,
    'min_child_weight': 1,
    'colsample_bytree': 0.8,
    'scale_pos_weight': 1,
    
    'metric': ['l1','l2'],

}


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25)

resultat = []
estimators_number = []
model = lgb.LGBMRegressor()

for i in range(10):
    
    time.sleep(0.5)
    
    hyper_params["n_estimators"] = 100 + i*10
    
    model.set_params(**hyper_params)
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, eval_set=[(X_test, y_test)], eval_metric='l2', early_stopping_rounds=50, verbose=False)

    ypred = model.predict(X_test)
    val = mean_squared_error(ypred, y_test)
  
    resultat.append(val)
    estimators_number.append(hyper_params["n_estimators"])
    
    print(val, estimators_number[-1], i)
    print()
```

So here I do 10 rounds for my for loop.

And increase the dictionary key "n_estimators" by 10 every rounds and set_parameters() of my model with my new parameters.

But despite those changes, my mse stay the same on test dataset.

```
0.3724475766885531 100 0

0.3724475766885531 110 1

0.3724475766885531 120 2

0.3724475766885531 130 3

0.3724475766885531 140 4

0.3724475766885531 150 5

0.3724475766885531 160 6

0.3724475766885531 170 7

0.3724475766885531 180 8

0.3724475766885531 190 9
```

How can you explain this and how to solve this ?

Comment: Since you have early stopping it's possible that the optimal number of trees is less than 100 and so even though you set a higher number in each iteration all of them stop at the same one.

Comment: @josemz I understand, but won't the parameters such as colsample_bytree and subsample add randomness to the training and thus change the result or at least minimally ?

Comment: There are seeds for bagging and feature_fraction which stay fixed here, so you'll get the same results every time.

Comment: @josemz Thanks, I didn't know from the documentation that there were fixed seeds for these parameters :)